# Linq and their sub queries

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a method that returns me a number of transactions, based on an accountId.

So, in my data accessor, I do this:

```
var items = (from c in Context.transactions where c.accountid == accountId select c).ToList();
```

I then call a method that I have that translates the entity framerwork objects, into my own custom DTO objects, and that then returns an object I pass through my service, logic and to my MVC controller.

The translater gets adjoining data. So, my custom DTO might have a field called 'AccountName string' and 'AccountType string'.

Account name is in a table that is foreign key'd to the Transaction table, and AccountType is then foreign key'd to the Account table.

So, my translater would look something like:

```
var return = new TransactionDto {
    tranactionId = source.id,
    accountName = source.Account.Description,
    accountType = source.Account.AccountType.description
}
```

I seem to have a speed issue, and I am wondering if my understanding of Linq is to blame. I thought that the `ToList()` on the initial data retrieval was the end of the select. It then passes all the data to `var items` .. but maybe my translater is actually doing a select for the 'Account' table, and then another select for the '`AccountType`' table. I mean, does the initial 'from `c in Context..`.' get all the foreign key'd tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called lazy loading. Use `Include` to eagerly load necessary navigation properties objects:

```
var items = Context.transactions
                   .Include("Account")
                   .Include("Account.AccountType")
                   .Where(x => x.accountId == accountId)
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin... so they way I am doing IS inneficient? The use of 'Include' will then create joins in the sql, and return one nice result set and pass a larger (but more eefective and efficient) model to my translater - and then no SQL calls will be performed within the Translate method?

Comment: Exactly. It will download all included properties in this one SQL query.